# gcc error messages

Tags: gcc, localization

I was trying to get error messages in spanish. I have changed the locale to es_EC.utf8.
I get messages in Spanish when I run apt-get etc., but gcc gives me errors in English. Can anybody help me?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, GCC-4.3.4

Comment: GCC might have been configured with `--disable-nls`, if it is then you'll have to recompile GCC.

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.3 looks like it has translations, whereas gcc 4.4 doesn't.

Check you have `gcc-4.3-locales` installed: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gcc-4.3-locales